# Display all the Geopoints on the map after parsing xml in Android

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I have parsed the xml code (by XML DOM Method) from my php which contains latitude,longitudes of list of POI's.I want to display all the points on the with pins from a separate class. The thing is I don't want listview when i open the app, it should open the map and display all the markers.Can someone help me on this? Thanks in advance.

Code

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

public class ParseXMLaroundme extends ListActivity{
 String latitude;
    public  ParseXMLaroundme () {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

        @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.aroundme);




            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

            String xml = ParseXMLMethods.getXML();
            Document doc = ParseXMLMethods.XMLfromString(xml);

            /*
            int numResults = ParseXMLMethods.numResults(doc);

            if((numResults <= 0)){
                Toast.makeText(ParseXMLDemo.this, "There is no data in the xml file", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
                finish();
            }
            */

            NodeList children = doc.getElementsByTagName("ListingElement");

            for (int i = 0; i < children.getLength(); i++) {                            
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();    
                Element e = (Element)children.item(i);
                map.put("ItemID", ParseXMLMethods.getValue(e, "ItemID"));
                map.put("ImageURL", ParseXMLMethods.getValue(e, "ImageURL"));
                map.put("VideoURL", ParseXMLMethods.getValue(e, "VideoURL"));
                map.put("AudioURL", ParseXMLMethods.getValue(e, "AudioURL"));
                map.put("StartDate", ParseXMLMethods.getValue(e, "StartDate"));
                map.put("EndDate", ParseXMLMethods.getValue(e, "EndDate"));
                map.put("ItemName", ParseXMLMethods.getValue(e, "ItemName"));
                map.put("Address", ParseXMLMethods.getValue(e, "Address"));
                map.put("Suburb", ParseXMLMethods.getValue(e, "Suburb"));
                map.put("Postcode", ParseXMLMethods.getValue(e, "Postcode"));
                map.put("Longitude", ParseXMLMethods.getValue(e, "Longitude"));
                map.put("Latitude", ParseXMLMethods.getValue(e, "Latitude"));
                map.put("SubtypeName", ParseXMLMethods.getValue(e, "Subtypename"));
                map.put("Cost", ParseXMLMethods.getValue(e, "Cost"));
                map.put("Details", ParseXMLMethods.getValue(e, "Details"));
                map.put("Website", ParseXMLMethods.getValue(e, "Website"));
                map.put("MajorRegionName", ParseXMLMethods.getValue(e, "MajorRegionName"));
                map.put("Phone", ParseXMLMethods.getValue(e, "Phone"));
                map.put("Email", ParseXMLMethods.getValue(e, "Email"));
                map.put("OpeningHours", ParseXMLMethods.getValue(e, "OpeningHours"));
                String targetlatitude=map.get("latitude");
                String targetlongitude=map.get("longitude");

                Double targetlat = Double.valueOf(targetlatitude);
                Double targetlng = Double.valueOf(targetlongitude);
                mylist.add(map);            
            }       


        /*



           ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist , R.layout.me_layout, 
                           new String[] { "Latitude", "Longitude", "VideoURL", "StartDate", "EndDate", "ItemName" }, 
                          new int[] { });

           setListAdapter(adapter);



            */

            final ListView lv = getListView();

            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {              
                    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                    HashMap<String, String> o = (HashMap<String, String>) lv.getItemAtPosition(position);                   
                    Toast.makeText(ParseXMLaroundme.this,o.get("NewsBody"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
                }
            });



        }
    }
```

Comment: u could parse xml file in starting activity n wn parsing is done, navigate to map activity with parsed data. For how to display multiple markers, refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7934978/how-to-draw-lots-of-markers-on-a-map

Comment: how do i navigate to new activity with parse data?

Comment: may b u could store parsed data in a static array or in a database and retrieve when u navigate to map activity

Comment: It's ok I got it working :). Thanks anyways